# javascript События jQuery

Tags: jquery, события

Всем, привет!
Мне нужно чтобы див менял свои свойства, когда внутри него производятся какие-то действия, ну, то есть, он в фокусе и терял их, когда перешли  в другое место. Я приведу пример на события mouseover и mouseout. А мне хотелось бы, чтобы было что-то типа focus. Но дело в том, что это не элемент формы.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){jQuery('.infoline').mouseover(function(){
    jQuery(this).closest('.infoline').find('.active').show();
    jQuery(this).closest('.infoline').css('background-color', '#f6f8fc')    
}); });

jQuery(document).ready(function(){jQuery('.infoline').mouseout(function(){
    jQuery(this).closest('.infoline').find('.active').hide();
    jQuery(this).closest('.infoline').css('background-color', '')
}); });
```

Этот большой див зовут .infoline. .active это полоска, появляющаяся справа для индикации активности дива.

Comment: что не так с предоставленным кодом?

Comment: Он работает. Но как только мышь ушла все пропало. А мне нужно, чтобы на клик, например, приобрел свойства, а при клике где-нибудь в другом месте потерял их. Чтобы оставался в фокусе, пока не уйдут из него в другое место.

Comment: так и делай на клик по нему ставь флаг, а по клику где-то еще убирай

Comment: Блин, я новичок. В jquery всего второй день. Тяжело так без закорючек перед глазами понять. Но за информацию спасибо. Отталкиваясь от нее, буду гуглить.

Comment: Юзай property http://api.jquery.com/prop/  и элемент checkbox например, от него стили сделай. Ну и вообще без jquery можно =)

Comment: Спасибо! Посмотрю. Изучу.